# UIBarButtonItem Custom using 20x20 and 40x40 white on transparent icon not using retina @2x

Tags: ipad, uibarbuttonitem, retina-display

I have custom UIBarButtonItems in my app and the images are not loading up the @2x on the new iPad 3. They seem to work on iPhone retina when in a simple toolbar but I have some custom code that requires some of these to be toolbars that are set to the right or left bar button item of the navigation bar.

UIBarButtonItem custom in navBar looks ok

UIBarButtonItem custom in UIToolbar looks ok

UIBarButtonItem custom in UIToolbar in UIBarButtonItem is messed up resolution.

This seems to work on my local build with Xcode 4.3 with iOS 5.1 SDK
This is not working on my build box with Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.0 SDK (WHAT!?)

Do i need to copy the image and specify ~ipad as well just to get it to know that I really meant use @2x on ipad retina?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Xcode 3? If so that is probably the problem here.

See the following related question:
[iPad 3 Retina Display, @2x images, and apps already in the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371780/ipad-3-retina-display-2x-images-and-apps-already-in-the-store)

Comment: Dev is on 4.3 Xcode build box is on 4.2. sdk on build is 5.0 and dev is on 5.1